# Serving protected files with Nginx X-accel-redirect and Django REST

Tags: nginx, django-rest-framework, x-accel-redirect

I can't understand where I'm wrong: if I disable Nginx location, Django REST viewset responds correctly. If I enable it, I obtain Nginx 404 not found.

nginx config

```
location /download {
    internal;
    alias /opt/myproject/media-protected;
}
```

Django REST viewset

```
class ServeProtectedFile(APIView):
authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)

def get(self, request):
    filename = self.kwargs['filename']

    userfile = UserFile.objects.get(filename=filename)
    response = HttpResponse()
    response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename={0}".format(userfile.filename)
    response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = "/download/{0}".format(userfile.file.name)
    return response
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^download/(?P<filename>[^/]+)/$', ServeProtectedFile.as_view()),
```

Comment: Maybe the url is wrong: should it be different from location?

Comment: Does 404 come from Django or nginx? What Django returns in X-Accel-Redirect header? Does the file with this path exist in /opt/myproject/media-protected ?